# How to parse a large XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have the below code wich will retrieve data from a XML file based on certain child value.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//Book[BookCode = "AD0WNR"] /Subject)');
?>
```

The code is working if I have few rows. But the main xml file is over 200mb and it does not retrieve anything. Could you please advise what I am doing wrong? Both small and large file have the same structure.

Comment: Do you see any error message from PHP or in web sever log?

Comment: (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/truckass/public_html/bookingassist.ro/test/test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing large documents like this I suggest using a streaming parser like [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) which will allow you to parse XML without loading the entire file into memory at once. By using its [`expand()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.expand.php) method it's easy to use it in hand with the DOM API.

Tree-based parsers like the DOM are very fast, but take up more memory as the entire document must be loaded up. Streaming parsers like XMLReader keep the memory use down as you're only grabbing a bit of the document at a time, but the trade off is longer processing time.

By using both you can adjust how you use each in tandem in order to get under any hard bounds like memory limits while minimizing processing time.

---

#### Example:

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('file.xml');

while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Book') {
        $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true);
        $result = $xpath->evaluate(
            'string(self::Book[BookCode = "AD0WNR"]/Subject)',
            $node
        );
        if ($result) {
            echo $result;
            $reader->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

What this is doing is iterating through the nodes in the XML. Whenever it hits an element `<Book>` we:

1. Import that into the DOM.
2. Evaluate the XPath expression<sup>*</sup>.

If the XPath expression found what we're looking for:

1. Print the result.
2. Close the file.
3. Break the read loop.

#2 and #3 we do because we're only looking for a single result. If you have more you want to find, remove those and keep on trucking.

---

*(* I've replace the initial double forward slash from the XPath expression with `self::` to act on the context node passed as the second parameter to `evaluate()` - thanks, [@ThW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535504/how-to-parse-a-large-xml-file/27536719?noredirect=1#comment43528208_27536719))*

Comment: How can i make to parse the document with SAX ?

Comment: now if i try to query 6 or 7 values, its taking 5 mins to load so its very unconvient

Comment: You don't need to append the expanded node. After import use the context argument of evaluate. `$xpath->evaluate('string(self::Book[BookCode = "AD0WNR"]/Subject)', $node);`